# Transform field in MongoDB aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregate

I have a some query on mongodb via aggregate, I can get the result I want and sent to client.
After this I need to be merge file name and file url.

My results

```json
{
  "_id" : "1", "name" : "x", "image" : "y.jpg"
}
```

But I want to edit results like this

```json
{
  "_id" : "1", "name" : "x", "image" : "http:/x.com/y.jpg"
}
```

I can edit the results after aggregate in a loop. but can aggregate give this to me as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/nWv7d2Ld5sy

Use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) and [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/)

```
   db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $set: {
          image: {
            $concat: [ "http://", "$name", ".com/", "$image" ] // combine to form the output
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

Comment: Thank you, But concat not support array. Actualy I asked the wrong question. My image field normaly array. I need to take the value contained in the array and change the array itself to concated string. I am trying now $project. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: @Kvlknctk add your sample data https://mongoplayground.net/p/nWv7d2Ld5sy and share new link

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/wlH6DKDSotW thank you for interest

Comment: @Kvlknctk check this https://mongoplayground.net/p/KP78Tj-m4il `$images.image`

Comment: How about this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/eK04iUPw_ec thank you again.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zav87tGnjvN here you go.

Comment: :)) you are awesome. I'll never forget your name.

Comment: @Kvlknctk Happy to help :)